# Are Functor and Functor pointer generally equal?

Tags: function-pointers, functor, c++98

Concerning the code below. I don't understand why Line III works. This means that a functor and a functor pointer are the same, at least in this case.
Can someone shed light on this.

Are they in general *equivalent*? Or only when passed as parameters?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct myprinter {
  void operator() (int i) {cout << i << ", ";}
};

int main() {
    int mynumbers[] = { 3, 9, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5 };
    vector<int> v1(mynumbers, mynumbers + 7);
    deque<int> d1(mynumbers, mynumbers + 7);
    set<int> s1(mynumbers, mynumbers + 7);
    //v1.pop_back(5);// Line I
    for_each(s1.begin(), s1.end(), myprinter());  // Line II
    for_each(d1.begin(), d1.end(), *(new myprinter()));  // Line III
    //for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), myprinter);  //Line IV
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: umm... `*(new myprinter())` is a `myprinter`, not a `myprinter` pointer.

Comment: I think it "*(new myprinter())" is the dereferencing of the object of "myprinter()". Not sure if that is what you meant, right?

Comment: `new myprinter()` is an expression of type `myprinter *` (it evaluates to a pointer to a dynamically-allocated instance of `myprinter`). Then the `*` operator dereferences the pointer, so you have a `myprinter` again.